# VPN, тунельный адрес у клиента и у сервера

Tags: linux, ip, vpn

У меня на виртуалке развернута Ubuntu и настроено VPN подключение. Как мне узнать тунельный адрес у клиента и у сервера.

Comment: через ifconfig не показывает клиентский адрес?

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov показывает, `tun0` `inet addr:10.20.20.201`, вроде бы то

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы посмотреть все подключения, используйте команду **ifconfig** с ключом -a.

```
ifconfig -a
```

tun или tap - это сети openvpn(в зависимости от конфигурации).